# Problem installing ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: software-installation, microsoft, ubuntu-restricted-extras

First thing, I'm far from a Linux wiz...

Based on some questions and answers around playing mp4 files, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras.
```

Things seemed to be going fine until I got a pop up with the Microsoft EULA and what appeared to be an <kbd>OK</kbd> button at the bottom.  Unfortunately, the button did nothing.  After waiting quite a while and trying whatever I could to accept the license, I killed the process... probably not the smartest thing do have done?

So now can anybody give me some help in either uninstalling what is there or doing a complete install?

TIA,

John

Comment: How did you 'kill the process' - close the terminal, or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is within a terminal window.  Were you trying to click the button with the mouse?

It's slightly counter-intuitive, but often the only way to move to those kind of buttons in the terminal is to use the Tab key.  I discovered this many years ago when I first started using Linux, and had trouble finding an answer to what must have been obvious to everyone else.

Anyways, open a terminal again.  `sudo apt-get -f install` will likely resume the installation you were just trying to do, if not, `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` again.  I'm not 100% sure that simply being unable to select the button was your actual problem.

So yeah, Tab to the button, Enter to select.  Very few command-line applications are mouse-enabled for obvious reasons.