# Stuck uninstalling ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: dpkg, ubuntu-restricted-extras

So, I tried to follow this site https://itsfoss.com/install-adobe-flash-player-in-ubuntu-13-04/
I wanted to install flashplugin
I ran `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
and got stuck in the following screen [Here's where it got stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUppw.png)
And after a while nothing happened at all. Tried to use ctrl+c to stop it, did nothing, only ctrl+z did anything, but then again, I tried to kill the terminal, and opened a new one to run the apt remove and said that dpkg was being used; then I tried to reboot and the system didn't give me the option to turn of the laptop so I used the terminal `sudo reboot` then I tried to use `sudo apt remove ubuntu-restricted-extras` and it said that it wasn't actually installed and removed two dependencies, when it got to the second one it gave me the same purple screen of death again stuck at 20%. How do I fix this? I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418312/problem-installing-ubuntu-restricted-extras)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what you are installing is under a proprietary EULA, `apt` wants you to confirm that you know what you are subjecting yourself to.

Just hit `<Tab>` and you should see that  button highlighted. Then hit `<Enter>`. You should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, lol
I wasn't understanding how to hit "OK"

Comment: Good to know it now works.

Comment: Hey @SashaNeedsHelp, if this is the correct answer can you please tick it as accepted? This way Andy get the credit.